# Openbravo: can't <Create Columns from DB>

Tags: openbravo

(I'm following the guide <[How_To_Create_a_Table](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50:Developers_Guide/How_To_Create_a_Table)>.)

In <Tables and Columns> I have created a new record, yet <Create Columns from DB> phails with:

> ```
> Error:
> The following mandatory columns are missing for this table:
> -primary key column named: HR_SALARY_ID
> -common column: UpdatedBy
> -common column: Updated
> -common column: IsActive
> -common column: CreatedBy
> -common column: Created
> -common column: AD_Org_ID
> -common column: AD_Client_ID
> Created = 0
> ```

The action is supposed to create the columns, so what could "columns are missing" mean?

What is causing the error?

---

The columns can be manually created in the bottompane.

---

Manually creating a <DB Column Name> in the bottompane, named `CreatedBy`, then re-running, gives:

> ```
> Error:
> The following mandatory columns are missing for this table:
> -primary key column named: HR_SALARY_ID
> -common column: UpdatedBy
> -common column: Updated
> -common column: IsActive
> -common column: Created
> -common column: AD_Org_ID
> -common column: AD_Client_ID
> Created = 0
> ```

---

Sql code to create table `HR_SALARY` is from [#1](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50:Developers_Guide/How_To_Create_a_Table#Create_new_tables_in_the_database).

---

Per `psql`:

```
openbravo=# select*from hr_salary;
 hr_salary_id | ad_client_id | ad_org_id | isactive | created | createdby | updated | updatedby | c_bpartner_id | amount | c_currency_id | validfrom
--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------------+-----------
(0 rows)


openbravo=#
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear i am openbravo developer i am happy to help.In openbravo `hr_salary_id | ad_client_id | ad_org_id | isactive | created | createdby | updated | updatedby` all the above fields are mandatory to create a custom table.First a table should be created in the database then the same table name should be given as DB Table Name,Table name then click in "Create Columns from DB" logically it will work.Hope it helps